# How do I count all the files that begin with letters from a to g?

Tags: shell, search

I have a question concerning linux commands. How do  I count all the files that begin with letters from a to g?

Comment: The file names, or the file contents? In a single directory, in a whole directory tree?

Answer (score 7):

```
LC_ALL=C
set -- [a-gA-G]*
if [ "$1" = '[a-gA-G]*' ]; then
  echo 0
else
  echo "$#"
fi
```

Comment: +1 for using shell internal commands only ;o)

Comment: You of all people might have mentioned zsh: `print -lr [A-Ga-g]*(N)` (or `print -lr (#i)[a-g]*(N)` if you want to be fancy).

Comment: @Gilles, You mean `n=0;: (#i)[a-g]*(Ne:'((!++n))':)` ? ;-)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Ah, oops, I somehow dropped “count” when I wrote this. `(a=((#i)[a-g]*(N)); echo $#a)` is less typing (and less cryptic).

Comment: @Gilles, I was going to say it's less efficient as it sorts the list (which you can disable with newers versions of zsh though) and stores it in memory, but in fact, it appears to be faster because for some reason mine causes zsh to do a lstat(2) on each file

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a one-line shell command:

```
find / -name '[abcedfg]*' -print | wc -l
```

You will see some messages about how `find` doesn't have permission to read some directory or another, but you will get a count of files whose names begin with those 7 letters.

Comment: any reason to specify [abcedfg] vs just [a-g]?

Comment: Just a habit for me. Those two shell globs should match the same file names, but I think seeing all the characters in a range is clearer, at least for small numbers of characters.

Comment: Note that files with newline characters in their path will be counted several times.

Comment: @foampile, the behavior of meaning ranges is locale dependant. `[a-g]` will match é in most non-ASCII locales contrary to `[abcdefg]`

Answer (score 3):

The GNU implementation of the  `ls` command (which you are using since you are running Linux) will find all files in the current directory starting with a character a-g.

```
ls --ignore='[!a-g]*'
```

It tells to ignore all files that do not start with a character in the range `[a-g]`. The `!` inverts the filter. `*` indicat

Next run the output through `wc -l` to count the lines.

The full command will thus be:

```
ls --ignore='[!a-g]*' | wc -l
```

This solution will not recurs into subdirectories.

Comment: I'm running Linux and my `ls` is implemented by BusyBox. Maybe you should explain why you're inverting the pattern then ignoring it, rather than just doing `ls [a-g]*` (I assume in order to handle the case of 0 matches, or the glob expanding into too many arguments.) And as @StephaneChazelas says in a comment to another answer, why not add `-d` to avoid recursing into directories?

Comment: @dubiousjim `-d` wouldn't help here as ls is not given any argument so it defaults to the current directory. With `-d`, it would just return "."

Answer (score 2):

GNU find can do that for you:

```
find ./ -type f -maxdepth 1 -iname "[a-g]*" 2> /dev/null | wc -l
```

this finds all files (not directories) under `./` but digs into no further directories and matches the name (case insensitive) of the file beginning with "a-g", redirects all errors to `/dev/null` and then counts the files

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -1 [a-g]* | wc -l
```

Why do it like this? Because you probably want the simplest answer; this one assumes you don't have to worry about not counting directories, nor searching sub-directories, nor upper-case filenames... and this is the command I most often use.

Comment: -1 is not necessary when the output is not to a terminal (like a pipe or socketpair (ksh93) above). What's the harm in adding a -d option and make it correct?